# Some data that are in UTF-8 such as 'æ' don't display correctly

Tags: php, excel, utf-8

I'm using the PHP port of John McNamara's Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
Perl package which can be found [here](http://www.bettina-attack.de/jonny/view.php/projects/php_writeexcel/).

It works great but I have some data that are in UTF-8 such as `æ` and it doesn't display correctly inside the resulting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using iconv fixes the problem.

```
$worksheet->write(0, 0, iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str));
```